# Match index and save in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have table with two columns:

| Index | Col_1 | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3,5 | 1001 |
| 2 | 4,5,6 | 2004 |
| 3 |  | 7845 |
| 4 | 1,6 | 9658 |
| 5 | 2,3 | 5236 |
| 6 |  | 6066 |

Need to check Col_1 and save the Key for each index number mentioned in the Col_1.

For Example: in Index 1, Col_1 has values 3,5 so need to save the Key of Index 3,5 in Key_Checked column. The Key saved will be 7845,5236

The output table should be:

| Index | Col_1 | Key | Key_Checked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3,5 | 1001 | 7845,5236 |
| 2 | 4,5,6 | 2004 | 9658,5236,6066 |
| 3 |  | 7845 |  |
| 4 | 1,6 | 9658 | 1001 |
| 5 | 2,3 | 5236 | 2004,7845 |
| 6 |  | 6066 |  |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# ensure we have strings everywhere
df = df.astype(str)

df['Key_Checked'] = (df['Col_1'].str.split(',').explode()
                     .map(df.set_index('Index')['Key']).dropna()
                     .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
                     .reindex(df.index, fill_value='')
                    )
```

output:

```
  Index  Col_1   Key     Key_Checked
0     1    3,5  1001       7845,5236
1     2  4,5,6  2004  9658,5236,6066
2     3         7845                
3     4    1,6  9658       1001,6066
4     5    2,3  5236       2004,7845
5     6         6066
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case if "Index" starts from 1 and has the type of "int64".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col_1": ["3,5", "4,5,6", np.NAN, "1,6", "2,3", np.NAN], "Key": ["1001", "2004", "7845", "9658", "5236", "6066"]}, index=range(1, 7))
df.fillna("", inplace=True)

df["Key_Checked"] = df.apply(lambda x:  "" if not x["Col_1"] else ",".join(df.loc[[int(i) for i in x["Col_1"].split(",")], "Key"]), axis=1)
```

[image]